# How do I add textviews to a screen?

Tags: android

I have an activity that requires a certain number of CheckedTextViews, depending on the length of a JSONArray. What is the best way to do this? Should I use an inflater? Or should I add it programmatically? Which is more efficient? How do I do both?

To make it more clear what I am trying to do:

I have a JSONArray and trying to add three textfields for each element in the jsonarray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think you should use an inflater and do it programmatically.

Define your view in XML to separate your design/layout and logic. Iterate trough the separate JSON entries, and inflate views while you need them.

The basic step would look something like this:

```
View inflatedView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.test, null); 
wrapper.addView(inflatedView);
```

(I put an example online once for a complete how-to. you can check it [here](http://androblip.huiges.nl/2010/05/14/add-a-view-to-a-wrapper-multiple-times-with-inflate/))

Comment: Well, no, not an sich. I don't have a lot of experience with the CheckedTextView, but the when the CheckedTextView is used in a ListView like the manual says it's usefull for, then you ofcourse might need one for the ListView as normal. But not when you're just adding them like you might add a TextView